# Bootstrap5 ms-auto not working as expected in row / column elements

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

So i'm trying to make the button move to the right side of the screen within the row element.
I have located both text and button in separated column elements first, then I'm trying to apply ms-auto to the second column element to move it to the right, but it's not working.

```html
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Listado de estudiantes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col ms-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-primary ms-auto" (click)="toogle()">Toogle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ms-auto` is not working because the `col` classes are making the columns grow to equal width. There are a few ways you could resolved this..

1_ use `col-auto` to shrink the 2nd column...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Listado de estudiantes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto ms-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toogle()">Toogle</button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

***or,***

2_ use `text-end` to right align the inline button...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Listado de estudiantes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toogle()">Toogle</button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo of both methods](https://codeply.com/p/0c1iEmLODB)